# WebAPI with ODATA - DerivesFrom show only child collection

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

Does it happened to any one?
The request return like this with only the specific fields.

```
  "odata.type":"GisEntityLayer","odata.id":"http://localhost:53809/odata/GisLayers()","EntityType":"Asset"
},{
  "odata.type":"GisImageLayer","odata.id":"http://localhost:53809/odata/GisLayers()","ImagePath":"C:\\Users\\michalc\\Downloads\\DSC_5378_.jpg"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate further? Show what your request is and what is the expected output etc.

Comment: I asked for http://localhost:53809/odata/GisLayers and I want to get the base fields from class GisLayer and the childs fields that I already have.